# Card has a different shadow for different row

Tags: android, card, elevation

Can't catch why the shadow for the card in each row is different?

[image]

Difference between card shadow in first row and in the last

[image]

Created it like that

```
@Composable
@Preview
fun DigitalKeyboardCompose(
 ...
) {
Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .onGloballyPositioned { size = it.size.toSize() },
        Arrangement.spacedBy(gap, Alignment.CenterVertically),
        Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
     repeat(3) { i ->
            Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(gap)) {
                repeat(3) { j ->
                    DigitalKeyboardKey(sizeInDP, i * 3 + j + 1, isEnabled, disableColor, onClick)
                }
            }
        }
     Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
            DigitalKeyboardKey(sizeInDP, 0, isEnabled, disableColor, onClick)
        }
    }

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun DigitalKeyboardKey(size: Dp, key: Int, isEnabled: Boolean, disableColor: Int, onClick: ((Int) -> Unit)?) {
    Card(
        elevation = 4.dp,
        modifier = Modifier.width(size).height(size),
        border = BorderStroke(1.dp, if (isEnabled) MaterialTheme.colors.primary else Color(disableColor)),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        enabled = isEnabled,
        onClick = { if (isEnabled) onClick?.invoke(key) }
    ) {
        Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
            Text(
                key.toString(),
                color = if (isEnabled) MaterialTheme.colors.primary else Color(disableColor),
                fontFamily = FontFamily.SansSerif,
                fontWeight = FontWeight(500),
                fontSize = TextUnit(28f, TextUnitType.Sp)
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the difference exactly?

Comment: The shadow of the card in the first row is lighter than in the second. On second than on third & so on.
In first row, it starts from #D6D6D6
second - #D1D1D1
third - #CDCDCD
fourth - #CBCBCB

It looks like elevation start to be bigger, bigger and bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/80644/where-are-the-light-sources-located-in-material-design) the light source in Android is positioned at an *altitude of 45 degrees* and an *angle of 90 degrees*. This should make some portions of screen receive more light than the others in order to create sense of depth and dimensionality.

This is the reason why the shadows for the components with the same elevation are cast differently on different parts of the screen.

Comment: You've found the cause, but `shadow` will have the same effect, as it's just another way to enable the same thing that `elevation` is doing. The native shadows actually use two light sources, an ambient and a spot. It's the spot light source that's causing the visual difference, and if the OP really wants even shadows everywhere, they'll need to disable the spot and intensify the ambient, which will require fiddling with theme attributes. Just FYI.

Comment: You're right. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I should've mentioned that I mean old-school XML theme attributes – `android:spotShadowAlpha` and `android:ambientShadowAlpha` – not through a Compose Theme. The ambient and spot properties are set for the whole `Window` at the time of its instantiation and they can't be changed, so Compose wouldn't be able do anything about it. It's not clear if the OP is asking for a "fix", or is just curious as to why it happens, but I thought I'd mention that before somebody wastes time messing with their `MaterialTheme` after reading my ambiguous comment above. Cheers!